# How can I revert SE appearance on mobile?

Tags: support, mobile-web, android, mobile-chrome

The appearance/ look of **English Language & Usage SE** has changed in my mobile phone and it was completely unexpected. It wasn't like this before. I use SE on Chrome in my mobile phone (Android).

It was like how it looks on PC. 
Also, lots of options are missing in this version. The old version was way better than this one and had many options.

For example, I'm unable to view history of the post, no options while editing or posting.

How do I revert it? Here's a screenshot of the new version (bluish one).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tap “full site” at the very bottom of the page. (You will need to dismiss the cookie notice at the bottom.)

[image: Image of said link]

(You may also be able to do this with your browser’s “request desktop site” option, if your browser has that. iOS Safari does, for example.)

There’s a “mobile” link on the full site’s footer to switch back to the mobile theme.